# Numerically stable algorithm for $(BC),$ when $(BC)^2=(AB)^2+(AC)^2-2(AB)(AC)\cos A,~(AB)\cong (AC),~A$ small

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle, such that the lenghts $(AB),~(AC)$ are almost equal and the angle $A$ is small. According to the cosine law:
>
> $$(BC)^2=(AB)^2+(AC)^2-2(AB)(AC)\cos A.$$
>
> (i) Explain why is the above algorithm numerically unstable for the evaluation of $(BC)$.
>
> (ii) Find a stable algorithm for the evaluation of $(BC).$

**Attempt.** $(i)$ Since angle $A$ is small, $\cos A$ is evaluated as $1$, so $(BC)\cong (AB)-(AC)$ and since $(AB)\cong (AC)$, we get a cancellation error.

$(ii)$ A way to start is to write $(BC)^2=((AB)-(AC))^2+4(AB)(AC)\sin^2(A/2)$, which still has some problems though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (i) I don't think you have correctly identified the error. If one of the other two angles also is small, then setting $BC$ to $AB - AC$ will give you an almost exactly correct answer. The problem then is that the cosine formula sometimes does _not_ set $BC$ to $AB - AC$. (ii) Please edit the question to explain what problems you found with the sine formula. William Kahan seems to think it's fine: see sec. 7 on page 6 of https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Triangle.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Regarding (i), I didn't quite get your point. First, why is there an issue on my remark?

Comment: You seem to be identifying $AB - AC$ as a source of cancellation error. I think in this case it isn't. I believe you _correctly_ identified the cosine function as a source of roundoff error, and there's also roundoff error in the squaring/multiplication, leading to what I suppose you might call a cancellation error (but it's more subtle than just  $AB - AC$). (Kahan just says the formula is "spoiled by roundoff error" but it's a very brief comment and he doesn't give any further detail.)